# Replace value in json files with variable values in shell script

Tags: linux, sed

I am creating multiple files from a json template file and I need to replace two values in json file by different values which I am storing in variable. Below is how source json look like

Source :

```
{"parameters": [
            {
                "name": "dir_parm",
                "value": "changethis"
            }
        ],
        "targets": [
            {
                "identifier": "hsotchangethis"
            }
        ]

}
```

Output what I require:

```
"parameters": [
            {
                "name": "dir_parm",
                "value": "/apps"
            }
        ],
        "targets": [
            {
                "identifier": "iass02"
            }
      ]
   }
```

In this way json file has to be updated for directory and host name around 40-50 times.

Below is the sed command I tried but it is getting replaced. File name, hostname , directory all are variables\dynamic.

```
sed -i '/identifier/c\ \"identifier\" : '${bdhostnm}'/g' $fname
```

Note- I read we can use jq but in the organization it is not allowed. Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: I am sorry, I mean sed command I used is not replacing host with the value in variable. It is either coming as empty or coming as bdhostnm

Comment: Have you tried using a tool, like [tag:jq], which is made especially for processing JSON?

Comment: jq is not available in the environment

Comment: Is [tag:python]?

Comment: @user19742249, In case you can install `jq`, then following could be helpful to you: `jq '.parameters[].value |= "/apps" | .targets[].identifier |= "iass02"' Input_file`

Comment: @user19742249, Your sample json was having issues, I have fixed it now in your question. Also added an `awk` solution in this post, cheers.

Comment: @user19742249 Since you haven't accepted any answer yet, is `python` installed in the environment? I asked you that a few days ago but I didn't get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As asked by user a sed solution:
Input

```
{"parameters": [
            {
                "name": "dir_parm",
                "value": "changethis"
            }
        ],
        "targets": [
            {
                "identifier": "hsotchangethis"
            }
        ]

}
```

```
value='/apps'  
bdhostnm='iass02'  
fname=file  
sed '/[ ]*"identifier":/{s/\("identifier": \)\(.*\)/\1'$bdhostnm'/g};/^[ ]*"value": /{s/\("value": \)\(.*\)/\1'${value/\//\\\/}'/g}' $fname
```

```
{"parameters": [
            {
                "name": "dir_parm",
                "value": /apps
            }
        ],
        "targets": [
            {
                "identifier": iass02
            }
        ]

}
```

Comment: This is not working as expected

Comment: I get message sed: -e expression #1, char 98: extra characters after command
and values are not getting repalced.

Comment: have you setted variables bdhosnm and value and fname

Answer (score 1):

Since OP doesn't have `jq` and can't install `jq` so coming up with this `awk` solution. Which is written and tested in GNU `awk`. Here I have created 2 `awk` variables named `valValue` and `valIdentifier` where NEW values for respective(json) fields should be mentioned in them.

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/97WCbP/1) for used regex in following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v valValue="/apps" -v valIdentifier="iass02" -v RS="" '
match($0,/^({"parameters": \[\n[[:space:]]+\
{\n[[:space:]]+"name": "dir_parm",\
\n[[:space:]]+"value": ")\
[^"]*("\n[[:space:]]+}\n\
[[:space:]]+\],\n[[:space:]]+\
"targets": \[\n[[:space:]]+\
{\n[[:space:]]+"identifier": ")\
[^"]*("\n[[:space:]]+}\n[[:space:]]+\
\]\n+[[:space:]]+})/,arr){
     print arr[1] valValue arr[2] valIdentifier arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case someone wants a `jq` code for this one(though its clearly not a ask in question here), then try like: `jq '.parameters[].value |= "/apps" | .targets[].identifier |= "iass02"' Input_file`.

Comment: In case someone looking for one-liner form of `awk` code try like: `awk -v valValue="/apps" -v valIdentifier="iass02" -v RS="" 'match($0,/^({"parameters": \[\n[[:space:]]+{\n[[:space:]]+"name": "dir_parm",\n[[:space:]]+"value": ")[^"]*("\n[[:space:]]+}\n[[:space:]]+\],\n[[:space:]]+"targets": \[\n[[:space:]]+{\n[[:space:]]+"identifier": ")[^"]*("\n[[:space:]]+}\n[[:space:]]+\]\n+[[:space:]]+})/,arr){print arr[1] valValue arr[2] valIdentifier arr[3]}'  Input_file`

Comment: value and target has to be modified as I have stored them in variables . json file has to be created for each target and value . When I try to valValue and valdentifier as variable , I am not getting results as expected.

Comment: @user19742249, both things could be done. Have `awk` like this: `awk -v valValue="$value" -v valIdentifier="$idenifier" -v RS="" 'match($0,/^({"parameters": \[\n[[:space:]]+{\n[[:space:]]+"name": "dir_parm",\n[[:space:]]+"value": ")[^"]*("\n[[:space:]]+}\n[[:space:]]+\],\n[[:space:]]+"targets": \[\n[[:space:]]+{\n[[:space:]]+"identifier": ")[^"]*("\n[[:space:]]+}\n[[:space:]]+\]\n+[[:space:]]+})/,arr){print arr[1] valValue arr[2] valIdentifier arr[3]}'  Input_file` I have virialized this program now, where `value` and `identifier` both are shell variables passed to `awk`. Run this.

Comment: @user19742249, continuing above comment here: Run this and see output on terminal once you are Happy we can save output into file, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @user19742249, you need to create shell variables then pass them to awk program just want to be clear here.

Comment: I tried above and json file is not getting replaced with values I have in variables. json file remains same.